# Returning html as a string in PHP

Tags: php, html, get

When I use CocoaRestClient to submit a GET on an HTML website it will return the source for the site.  How can I return the same thing as a string (or something to convert into a string or parse) in php?  I've tried using

```
    echo $_GET[$url];
```

but it does not seem to return anything.

Note: the string returned will probably be rather large.

Comment: Is there anyhing in $_get? Also try url rather than $url

Comment: Did you mean `echo $_GET["url"]`? Note however that there are limits on how big a GET parameter can be (about 1-2k)

Comment: $_GET['url']; will be what is in the url: index.php?url=asd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about how to make an HTTP request from PHP and get the response as a string, for the simplest cases you can use [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

If you want to do something more configurable then you have to go with [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you.  On to figuring out the next step! Also, looking into curl to see if that's more of what I need.  Thank you sir.

Comment: @JuJoDi, if this answer was what you're looking for, please mark as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to prevent sending the source to the visitor's browser and get it as a string instead? You can use output buffer.

Put this line at the beginning of your code:

```
ob_start();
```

From now on everything that would normally be sent to the browser will be buffered instead. To end buffering and get contents use:

```
$out = ob_get_contents();    // this will only get the contents
$out = ob_get_clean();       // this will also empty the buffer
```

To stop buffering:

```
ob_end_clean();              // will just stop buffering
ob_end_flush();              // will also echo() current buffer
```

[Output buffer docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).